# In this context, is there anyway I can use requests.post() without also using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've spent the day day and-a-half (I'm a beginner) trying to work out how to do something simple: Fill in an ID code and hit 'search'. I've read the requests docs and scoured stack overflow for examples, but none seem to help me.

What I want to do is run through a list of IDs that I have and check off which one's are valid and which are invalid. (This is for academic research)
Here's my code:

```
import requests
url = 'https://ndber.seai.ie/pass/ber/search.aspx' 

payload = {'ctl00$DefaultContent$BERSearch$dfSearch$txtBERNumber':'100000000'
}
#the above dictionary key corresponds to the name , found using Firefox inspector in the source code. 
#I have tried using input ID too with no difference in outcome
#enter in arbitrary number of '100000000'- expect to see 'Invalid ID Number' printed


r = requests.post(url, data = payload)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(r.text)
if 'Number.'in r.text: #'Number' is an arbitrary word that happens to be in the page if a correct ID code is entered
    print('Valid ID Number')
elif 'No results found.' in r.text: #as above, 'No results found' is in the page if an incorrect ID is entered
    print('Invalid ID Number') #with the aboove number entered, I would expect this line to be printed
else:
    print('Code Failure') #this line gets printed
```

I've tried to comment it as much as possible, so you can see what I'm at.
The output I get is `Code Failure`

The reason why BeautifulSoup comes into all this is because I asked for help on Reddit's excellent 'learn python' subreddit yesterday. A Redditor generously took the time to try to explain where I went wrong and what I should do differently. Here's what (s)he suggested I do:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibpqq.png), which involves BS4.

So, is the Redditor right, or can this be done in a simple and 'light' way using the requests library?

Cheers!

Comment: Would appreciate if someone could explain why I'm not getting any response to this. Is the question in some way incorrectly formatted? Did I include too much/too little information? Is it too long?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to simulate exact same post with parameters, you can use firefox's firebug to see what parameters are beeing sent.
Below you can see the parameters, I've seen.

```
__EVENTARGUMENT=
__EVENTTARGET=
__EVENTVALIDATION=/wEdAAUFK13s0OHvBcOmXYSKCCYAA5nYY19nD30S2PPC/bgb6yltaY6CwJw6+g9S5X73j5ccPYOXbBJVHSWhVCIjHWYlwa4c5fa9Qdw0vorP2Y9f7xVxOMmbQICW5xMXXERtE7U18lHqXqDZVqJ8R/A9h66g
__SCROLLPOSITIONX=0
__SCROLLPOSITIONY=114
__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwULLTE2MDEwODU4NjAPFgIeE1ZhbGlkYXRlUmVxdWVzdE1vZGUCARYCZg9kFgICAw9kFgICAw8WAh4FY2xhc3MFC21haW53cmFwcGVyFgQCBQ8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVnZGQCCQ9kFgICAQ9kFgxmD2QWAgIBD2QWAgIBD2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFgQCAQ8WAh4JaW5uZXJodG1sZWQCAw9kFgICAg9kFgJmD2QWBAIBD2QWAgIDDw8WCh4EXyFTQgKAAh4MRGVmYXVsdFdpZHRoHB4EVGV4dAUFY3RsMDAeB1Rvb2xUaXAFPlBsZWFzZSBlbnRlciBhIHZhbHVlLCB3aXRoIG5vIHNwZWNpYWwgY2hhcmFjdGVycywgd2l0aCBubyB0ZXh0HgVXaWR0aBxkZAIDD2QWAgIDDw8WCh8EAoACHwUcHwYFCTEwMDAwMDAwMB8HBT5QbGVhc2UgZW50ZXIgYSB2YWx1ZSwgd2l0aCBubyBzcGVjaWFsIGNoYXJhY3RlcnMsIHdpdGggbm8gdGV4dB8IHGRkAgQPFCsAAmQQFgAWABYAFgJmD2QWAgICD2QWAmYPPCsAEQIBEBYAFgAWAAwUKwAAZAIGDxYCHwJoFgQCAQ8WAh8CaGQCAw9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAgIBDxYCHwJoZAIIDxYCHwJoFgQCAQ8WAh8CaGQCAw9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAgIBDxYCHwJoZAIKDxYCHwJoFgQCAQ8WAh8CaGQCAw9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAgIBDxYCHwJoZAIMDxYCHwJoFgQCAQ8WAh8CaGQCAw9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCAgMPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAgIBDxYCHwJoZBgBBTNjdGwwMCREZWZhdWx0Q29udGVudCRCRVJTZWFyY2gkZ3JpZFJhdGluZ3MkZ3JpZHZpZXcPZ2QPHVcTs3MrN3SZqli/KiHgWASd1DRvCLPuS7Rs+GRQAQ==
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=1F9CCB97
ctl00$DefaultContent$BERSearch$dfSearch$Bottomsearch=Search
ctl00$DefaultContent$BERSearch$dfSearch$txtBERNumber=2313131
ctl00$DefaultContent$BERSearch$dfSearch$txtMPRN=11111111111
```

And belowe code just worked,

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import requests
url = 'https://ndber.seai.ie/pass/ber/search.aspx' 

payload = {'__EVENTVALIDATION':'/wEdAAUFK13s0OHvBcOmXYSKCCYAA5nYY19nD30S2PPC/bgb6yltaY6CwJw6+g9S5X73j5ccPYOXbBJVHSWhVCIjHWYlwa4c5fa9Qdw0vorP2Y9f7xVxOMmbQICW5xMXXERtE7U18lHqXqDZVqJ8R/A9h66g',
           '__VIEWSTATE':'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',
           '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':'1F9CCB97',
           'ctl00$DefaultContent$BERSearch$dfSearch$Bottomsearch':'Search',
           'ctl00$DefaultContent$BERSearch$dfSearch$txtBERNumber':'2313131',
           'ctl00$DefaultContent$BERSearch$dfSearch$txtMPRN':'11111111111'
}
session = requests.session()
r = requests.post(url, data=payload)
if 'Number.'in r.text: #'Number' is an arbitrary word that happens to be in the page if a correct ID code is entered
    print('Valid ID Number')
elif 'No results found.' in r.text: #as above, 'No results found' is in the page if an incorrect ID is entered
    print('Invalid ID Number') #with the aboove number entered, I would expect this line to be printed
else:
    print('Code Failure') #this line gets printed"""
```

Just put your parameters in the payload dictionary, rest of the parameters can stay they I think

BER/DEC Number > ctl00$DefaultContent$BERSearch$dfSearch$txtBERNumber

MPRN  > ctl00$DefaultContent$BERSearch$dfSearch$txtMPRN